# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80004005)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I developed a school DBMS using ASP.NET and SQL Server, and I tried to transfer to another system then I installed SQL Server 2014. After going on my through my default page inserting my user and pass all that will display is :

> Unable to establish connection to database.
>
> Error information:
>   Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80004005)
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>
> Other possible cause of this problem:
>   The database cannot be opened, most likely due to incorrect connection settings or insufficient security set on your database folder or file.

Can you please let know what would be issue.

Comment: Ok, so, what is your connection string?

Comment: The error means that your connection string is bad.  What I do is open SSMS that comes with SQL server, hopefully you've installed it, login using the tool & based on what I had to do, I replicate it in my connection string (Which you need to post).  There's obviously a set of syntax & rules around this, but you need to learn it to work with this stuff.

Comment: please be more clear

Comment: Whenever I have seen 80004005 it has been permission restrictions.  Aside from confirming a connection string, I would try login as an Admin user, test and see if still a crash or not.

Answer (score 0):

Had this before, follow this guide

TLDR: Change the provider to SQLOLEDB.1

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fab0e3bf-4adf-4f17-b9f6-7b7f9db6523c/communication-link-failure-when-connecting-to-remote-database?forum=sqlintegrationservices

```
SOURCE:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946265/ssis-package-creating-hresult-0x80004005-description-login-timeout-expired-e
```

Comment: that was the provider i used

Comment: Will most likely be account permissions then